# Exception attempt to invoke virtual method - WebView Android

Tags: android, xml, exception, webview, error-handling

I'm having a issue with webview in Android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEn);
       wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mywv);
       //webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       //webView.loadUrl("https://mobile.twitter.com/SelbyHigh");
       ------<Error occuring here under this line>------
       wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
       wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);        
       wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 
       wv.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
       String content = "https://mobile.twitter.com/SelbyHigh";
       wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
       wv.loadUrl(content);
       btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

And here is a Snapshot of the exception. My activity doesn't runs when I call it.
[Image Link]http://s13.postimg.org/pjlwlsnuv/errorpng.png
The error occurs somewhere when it tries to reach getsettings() function as I know. Please if you have a answer, Post it under this. If you want me to provide more details then comment on this question. Thank you.

Comment: Your webview object is null. please check the layout xml for webview id!

Comment: ok! I will add an answer make it accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webview is null because you haven't made a call to `setContentView()`.

Call `setContentView()` before making any `findViewById()` call.

Comment: Thanks for better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your webview object is null. please check the layout xml for webview id!